# How to access the "transform" attribute of CSS3 with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, css, rotation, transform

How can I access the CSS "transform" attribute using JavaScript? I tried this but it didn't allow me:

```
function hoverFun(x)
{
x.style.opacity="1";
x.style.transform="rotate(180deg)";
x.style.cursor="pointer";
}
```

It doesn't recognize "rotate(180deg)". What should I do? How should I type it? Help please!

Comment: With jQuery you could use the .css() selector, would probably solve your problems.

Answer (score 0):

You just need CSS3 for this:

**http://jsfiddle.net/SzMmT/2/**

```
.box
{
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background: blue;
    opacity: 0.7;
}
.box:hover
{
    transition: 1s;
    -webkit-transition: 1s;
    -moz-transition: 1s;
    transform: rotate(360deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(360deg);
    cursor: pointer;
    opacity: 1;
}
```

Comment: Considering all he wants to do is rotate it on hover, that would definitely be better than using javascript.

Answer (score 0):

The CSS property transform is still a working draft (W3C Draft - http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css-transforms/), so you will need to use browser prefix's for the browsers you are targeting. For example:

```
x.style.webkitTransform="rotate(180deg)"; // webkit based browsers (Chrome, Safari, etc.)
x.style.mozTransform="rotate(180deg)"; // mozilla based browsers (Firefox)
x.style.msTransform="rotate(180deg)"; // Internet Explorer
x.style.oTransform="rotate(180deg)"; // Opera
x.style.transform="rotate(180deg)"; // support for future standard
```